# vertex percolation in an infinite graph

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, random-graphs, borel-cantelli-lemmas, percolation

Suppose that $G=(V,E)$ is an infinite graph with finite degrees where every vertex is black with probability $p$.

The black subgraph is a subgraph whose vertices are black and the edges are edges between black vertices.

I am trying to find if:

1. The number of connected components is constant with probability 1.
2. The event that there are infinitely many connected components is a $0-1$ event.
3. Will the answers change if we allow infinite degrees?

It's pretty clear that kolmogorov 0-1 law and borel-cantelli lemmas will play a part here... However, I can't figure out the right way to use them.